# Does the phrase "не за что!" have two meanings?

Tags: idioms

I vaguely remember discussing the phrase "не за что!" with my Russian teacher and I believe that he said the phrase has different meanings when spoken in different ways.

I do remember that one meaning is basically "Hell no!" What is the correct intonation/pronunciation for the phrase when its delivered with this meaning?

Is there another meaning when the phrase is spoken with a different intonation/pronunciation? If so, what is it and how do I say it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `"Не за что"`

(phrase stress on the first word) is widely used as synonym phrase to `"Пожалуйста"` but with the meaning closer to `"Not at all"` rather than to `"You are welcome"`.

compare with,

> `"Ни за что"`

(phrase stress on the last word) means `"Hell no!"` or `"The hell I will!"`.

Edit: As Andrey Chernyakhovskiy correctly added in his comment,

While these phrases are often used idiomatically, they themselves are not idioms.

`Не за что` literally means `'there is nothing [to ... for/at/behind]'`:

> `не за что благодарить` means `"there is nothing to thank for"`,
>
> `его не за что винить` means `"there's nothing to blame him for"`,
>
> `не за что глазу зацепиться` means `"there's nothing for the eye to be caught at"`,
>
> `не за что спрятаться` means `"there's nothing to hide oneself behind"`.

It is a particular case of a generic template `не` + preposition + `кто/что` in relevant case which is quite ubiquitous.

Comment: +1 for excellent idiomatic equivalents

Comment: While these phrases are often used idiomatically, they themselves are not idioms. *Не за что* literally means 'there is nothing [to ... for/at/behind]': *не за что благодарить* 'there is nothing to thank for', *его не за что винить* 'there's nothing to blame him for', *не за что глазу зацепиться* 'there's nothing for the eye to be caught at', *не за что спрятаться* 'there's nothing to hide oneself behind'. It is a particular case of a generic template *не + preposition + кто/что in relevant case* which is quite ubiquitous.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy yes, nice comment. Will you post this information in your own answer or you would like me to include it to this answer?

Comment: Please include it in your answer.

Comment: Thank you @AndreyChernyakhovskiy for your contribution, I added that.

Answer (score 10):

> I do remember that one meaning is basically "Hell no!"

This phrase was *ни за что́*, not *не́ за что*, and is pronounced with accent on *что*, while *glad to help* phrase *не́ за что [благодари́ть]* is pronounced with accent on *не*.

Full form of *ни за что́* would be *ни за что́ на све́те*, meaning no possible reward would make the speaker to agree to something.

Answer (score 4):

There is also an idiom "Ни за *что* ни про *что*". It means "for nothing", "without a reason".

For example "Человека избили ни за что ни про что!".

Answer (score 3):

I am a native Russian speaker and it's hard to imagine other meaning of this phrase except this one :

> "Not at all!"

Basically, this phase is used when somebody wants to say `"Thank you"` to you and you pronounce this phrase in order to show that this was very easy for you, as you would answer "You shouldn't thank me at all " but "thanks" is omitted.

Answer (score 3):

You can say "Не за что" meaning "Это не стоит того". For example "благодарить эту страну не за что".

Comment: @Jacob Your example is very good indeed, we all know what country did you have in mind :-)